# Which public-key cryptosystems are used the most?

Tags: public-key

Does anybody know if there is some kind of measure on how often public-key cryptosystems like El Gamal, RSA,... are implemented. Which ones are most common?

Comment: Obviously, RSA. Thanks to RSA Security LLC and SSL/TLS.

Comment: Although, if you include key agreement systems, I'm sure DH/ECDH comes in as a very strong second...

Comment: The title asks for 'used' (formerly, 'use'), the question asks for 'how often implemented', these are different things, and loosely defined. If you count each signature verification as 'use', I think it is RSA, thanks to digital certificates where it rules. If you count cryptograms generated (thus discount signature verification), I think ECDH might come first, because many https transaction now start with that. How do you count 'implementations' when software is replicated? Each EMV Smart Card uses RSA, many also have ECC hardware and code but does not use it.